# Concatenate string literals with DirectoryInfo enumeration and adding quotation marks.

Tags: c#, concatenation, double-quotes, directoryinfo, lpr

This seems like such an obscure question, but here it goes:

Is there a way to concatenate String Literals with a DirectoryInfo enumeration (which contains a file path) while adding quotations around the file path? Further, how can I prevent backslashes from being doubled when converting a DirectoryInfo enumeration to a string? My situation is as follows:

```
DirectoryInfo filePathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
Process a = new Process();

a.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\lpr.exe";
a.StartInfo.Arguments = "-SServername.Domain.net -Plp " + "\"" + filePathDirectory + "\"";
a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
a.Start();
a.WaitForExit();
```

`filePathDirectory` starts with a value of:

```
{\\ServerName\Share\Folder\Folder\FileName.xls}
```

Which I think is converted into a string once concatenated into `a.StartInfo.Arguments` which is assigned the value of:

```
-SServername.Domain.net -Plp \"\\\\ServerName\\Share\\Folder\\Folder\\FileName.xls\"
```

This is bad because, the number of backslashes in the path doubled. How can I ensure no backslashes are added to the path?

On top of that, to add a quotation marks, I've used the backslash escape sequence; But the backslash from this escape sequence is inadvertently added to my string. How can I add quotation marks around the file path which is contained in `a.StartInfo.Arguments`?

P.S. I hope this makes sense, please ask questions if you need clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes are not doubled and the backslash of the quotes also "isn't there". You can verify it by `Console.WriteLine(a.StartInfo.Arguments)` or `MessageBox.Show(a.StartInfo.Arguments)`.

What you are seeing - in the debugger I assume - is the representation of the string with the escape characters *not* translated - just as you would need to enter it in the IDE.

Example:

```
string s = "\"";
```

This will show in the debugger as `"\""` but it will display on screen as `"`:

[image]

Comment: You're right. I just _thought_ this was causing an issue with my process, when in fact it seems to be something else which will require a new question on my part.