# Unhandled C# Exception during an LPR process

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, unhandled-exception, lpr

I'm creating a C# app that should use lpr.exe and pass arguments to it. I'm currently trying to do it this way:

```
DirectoryInfo filePathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);              
Process a = new Process();
a.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\lpr.exe";
a.StartInfo.Arguments = "-SServerName.Domain.net -Plp " + "\"" + filePathDirectory + "\"";
a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
a.Start();
a.WaitForExit();
```

But whenever I get to `a.Start();` I get an unhandled Win32 exception which states "The system cannot find the file specified". This is really confusing me becuase, at first I thought it was my arguments, but turns out, I can pass the exact same arguments from a VB app and get it to work.

**Update 1:**

The VB code that works is:

```
Dim RPname As String
RPname = FileName.ToString
Dim a As New Process
a.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\system32\lpr.exe"
a.StartInfo.Arguments = "-SServerName.Domain.net -Plp " & Chr(34) & RPname & Chr(34)
a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
a.Start()
a.WaitForExit()
```

What's more is that my issue doesn't seem to be with the arguments statement, as I can comment it out and I still receive the error.

**Update 2:**

The error I get at the start of the process is: *The system cannot find the file specified.* I do not get the error if I change the FileName to "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", that works fine...

Comment: This smells like permissions issues... Is your c# app running with full trust?  Also, is the other app VB classic or VB.NET?

Comment: The same trust as my VB app. And how do I discern whether it is classic or .NET? (I feel rather inept asking)

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012, the other app is vb.net.  You would have to use the old 32 bit VB5 / 6 compiler that doesn't even run on Vista or above.  Oh - and show us your vb code then!

Comment: I've updated my question. And I'm definitely **not** using VB classic :P

Comment: The code is different... In the VB version, you're just concatenating the string filename into the .Arguments property. In the C# version you're concatenating filePathDirectory, which is not the same.

Comment: I have no idea, and had no clue that doing so would cause problems. But using a string of the same path doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: Have you compared the values for .Arguments in the debugger?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint before calling a.Start(), and check the contents of a.StartInfo.Arguments.  Make sure the arguments are what you expect.

Comment: I used Console.WriteLine to confirm that both produce the same arguments. Altough, hovering over the .Arguments while debugging will show more backslashes than the VB version. As I found out in an earlier question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531976/concatenate-string-literals-with-directoryinfo-enumeration-and-adding-quotation

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **[DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)** object in your c# code and concetanate it. Try to change your code to this:

```
try
{
  DirectoryInfo filePathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);              
  Process a = new Process();
  a.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\syswow64\lpr.exe";  // ADAPTED to the new path!! worked!
  // use filePathDirectory.FullName!!
  a.StartInfo.Arguments = "-SServerName.Domain.net -Plp " + "\"" + filePathDirectory.FullName + "\"";
  // or change it to - found it more readable imo
  a.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(
                               "-SServerName.Domain.net -Plp \"{0}\"", 
                               filePathDirectory.FullName);
  a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  a.Start();
  a.WaitForExit();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**EDIT**

Found the solution to your problem! First - credits go to @Sundeep according to his [**given answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543052/lpr-command-not-working-from-my-c-sharp-program-in-win-7). He pointet me to a [**webSite**](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/240019-34-error-windows) indicating that

> Yes I have, but **64-bit files** located in c:\windows\system32 **is not
>   seen by a 32-bit command prompt** (c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe) which is
>   launched when call at batch file from a 32-bit application.

And furthermore

> ... trying to get a 32 bit program to launch
>   lpr.exe inside of Windows 2008 R2. **It fails because lpr.exe does not
>   exist in the 32 bit view of the O/S.** ...
>
> For a work-around, I **copied lpr*.* from a 32 bit O/S system32 folder
>   into SYSWOW64** on the 2008 R2 machine...

Comment: This did not solve my problem. What's more is that I can remove the arguments statement, and I still get an error when 'a.Start();' occurs

Comment: added try catch block. pls provide **which kind of exception** has been thrown and **what error message** you got!

Comment: can you do this ? use C:\Windows\System32\lpr.exe in run and check if that works or not. I know I sound stupid but can you check this and let me know

Comment: I don't have a `c:\windows\System32\lpr.exe` file on my computer! won't work.. What execption do you get?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I will set up a try catch block as soon as I can. Also, I had to enable lpr services on my machine to get lpr.exe.

Comment: @Pradie Yes, I can run C:\Windows\System32\lpr.exe, even from the command line.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I got the old "The system canoot find the file specified" error. Keep in mind, I get this error whether or not the Arguments line is in place or not.

Comment: I posted an answer to this question even though it is very old, as, although PlgestorgerFranz's answer is correct, a better workaround is available:  use the sysnative virtual directory, instead of copying the system32 file to the syswow64 directory.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
DirectoryInfo filePathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);              
Process a = new Process();
a.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\lpr.exe";
a.StartInfo.Arguments = "-SServerName.Domain.net -Plp " + "\"" + filePathDirectory + "\"";
a.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
a.Start();
a.WaitForExit();
```

Pilgerstorfer Franz' explanation is exactly right, but especially in an environment like mine, going and moving the location of the lpr.exe on every machine is a lot of work.  The simple solution is to use the sysnative directory.

http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm

> The 'Sysnative' folder is invisible in Windows Explorer    If you
>   start Windows Explorer and open the Windows folder on your hard disk,
>   you may notice that the Sysnative folder is not shown. The main reason
>   to this is that Windows Explorer is a 64-bit program (when run in a
>   64-bit Windows), and the Sysnative folder is only visible and
>   accessible from 32-bit software. If 64-bit software need access to the
>   64-bit system folder in Windows, the only option is to use the
>   System32 folder name (for example: C:\Windows\System32).
>
> Using the 'Sysnative' folder will help you access 64-bit tools from
>   32-bit code    Some tools in a 64-bit Windows only exist in a 64-bit
>   version; there is no 32-bit version available. And some of these tools
>   are located in the 64-bit System32 folder. One example is the nbtstat
>   tool that is used to help troubleshoot NetBIOS name resolution
>   problems. If you try to run the nbtstat tool from 32-bit code (for
>   example from an application or from script) and use a path like
>   C:\Windows\System32, you will get a "File not found" error. The file
>   can not be found; although Windows Explorer shows that the nbtstat
>   program file actually is located in the C:\Windows\System32 folder.
>   The solution to this (somewhat confusing) problem is to include the
>   virtual Sysnative folder in the folder path when you want to run the
>   tool. For example like this:   C:\Windows\Sysnative\nbtstat.exe    The
>   file path above will give you access to the 64-bit nbtstat tool from a
>   32-bit application or from a 32-bit script. We recommend you to read
>   this article / blog post (at Scottie’s Tech.Info) to get more details
>   about this.